# How do I calculate CV of triplicates in R?

Tags: r

I have 1000+ rows and I want to calculate the CV for each row that has the same condition.

The data look like this:

```
    Condition     Y
    0.5           25
    0.5           26
    0.5           27
      1           43
      1           45
      1           75
      5           210
      5           124
      5           20
     10           54
     10           78
     10           10
```

and then I did:

```
CV <- function(x){ 
                 (sd(x)/mean(x))*100
               } 
             CV.for every row. <- aggregate(y ~ Condition,
                         data = df,
                         FUN = CV)
```

I have the feeling that what I did, uses the mean of the whole column, cause the results are a bit whatever.

Comment: Looks legit to me.

Comment: What do you mean? I get odd results!

Comment: So you want to apply the function (sd(x)/mean(y))*100 to Y across each Condition group, correct?

Comment: @user12237608 Define odd perhaps a sample output might help. I also get similar result using your function when compared to the output of `cv` from  `raster` package.

Comment: @J.G yes correct. Odd results like CV = 100000 which is crazy